# How can I install Easy_Install for Python 2.6.4 in Mac OSX 10.4.11

Tags: python, easy-install

I get the following errors, I've placed [my name] for anonymity:

```
>>> python /Users/[myname]/Desktop/setuptools-0.6c11/ez_setup.py 
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python /Users/[myname]/Desktop/setuptools-0.6c11/ez_setup.py 
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If you can't see the ^ is under the 11.

Or I get this error:

```
>>> python /Users/[myname]/Desktop/EZ_tutorial/ez_setup.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'python' is not defined
```

Comment: Hi Diego, welcome to SO.  When you need a monospace font, you can highlight your text and press ctrl-k.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ez_setup.py script may or may not work depending on your environment. If not, follow the instructions [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).  In particular, from the shell, make sure that the python 2.6 you installed is now invoked by the command `python`:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75821M, Oct 27 2009, 19:48:32) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ^D
```

If not, modify your shell's PATH environment variable.  Then download the setuptools 2.6 python egg from [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools), change to your brower's download directory, and run the downloaded script:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads   # substitute the appropriate directory name
$ sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
```

Comment: I get the following error when trying your first recommendation:

  
>>> sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  
that is shown at 0.6c11
  
the second code you showed returned the following:
  
NameError: name 'cd' is not defined

Comment: You are still trying to execute shell commands inside of the Python interpreter!  The prompt you see should be something like `$` not `>>>`.  Notice the `^D`: that means typing the `Control` and `D` keys simultaneously and that should return you to the shell.

Answer (score 2):

Try running that command from a shell (i.e. straight from Terminal.app), not from inside the python interpreter.

Comment: if you have a `>>>` you're in the python shell. Exit out of it using `quit()`.